# Proof that gaussian integers are an integral domain by contradiction.

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, integral-domain, gaussian-integers

I just want to make sure my proof is alright, I would appreciate some hints for a direct proof also. What I have doesn't feel very elegant.

Assume for contradiction that $\alpha, \beta$ are zero-divisors in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then,
$$
 (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i=0
 $$
To be zero both $\operatorname{Re}(\alpha\beta)=0$ and $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha\beta)=0$, so $ac-bd=0$ and $bc+ad=0$. Then $ac=bd$ and $bc=-ad$, multiplying both sides of $ac=bd$ by $c$ and substituting in for $bc$ gives that $acc = -add$, but this gives $c^2=-d^2$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: We know that $\mathbb{C}$ has no zero divisors, so it follows that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: Your argument doesn't cater for the case when $a = 0$. As suggested in the other comment why not work in $\Bbb{C}$ and show that every non-zero element has an inverse (in $\Bbb{C}$) and hence cannot be a zero divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is already too late, maybe there is a better way to see why your proof is wrong. You see, one of the reasons we want to show something is an integral domain is that *cancellation property* holds in integral domain. See for the ring $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, $2 \cdot 4 = 2 \cdot 1$, but $4 \ne 1$ as a counterexample.

You can, of course, try to manipulate the terms and see if you have any luck. However, the best way is to realize $\mathbb{Z}[i] \subset \mathbb{C}$. From there you can either prove $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as a subring (and there is already no zero divisors in $\mathbb{C}$ or use polar coordinates representation (and realize how surpringsly easy it is!))

Some people would suggest using *norm*. However, by definition, a norm is only defined on integral domain, so I guess $\mathbb{C}$ is your only hope...